# Is it possible to disable "Compute measure variations" (o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor) subtask from the report generating background task?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

SonarQube Version: 6.0

I am experiencing a sudden increase in background task (related to report generation by the sonar-server) completion time from about 3 minutes to 30 minutes.

My project is like below:

```
100K LOC
30K issues
Mysql DB size 4 GB
Project_Measure table has about 12 million rows
```

From the analysis log, I can see that the following two items are taking most time. Is it possible to disable or ignore "Compute measure variations" (o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor) to avoid the long delay? Any sort of advice is welcome.

```
2016.10.03 15:17:07 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Execute component visitors | time=9680ms
2016.10.03 16:12:26 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute measure variations | time=3318787ms
```

Comment: you didn't provide the version of SonarQube

Comment: There is no way to disable this step. You can try enabling trace logs and see if there is an obvious location consuming this time (my guess would be it's DB related so some SQL request may be very slow).

Comment: Do you mean, trace log for background task? I did not know that is possible. I know how to enable detail log for sonar-scanner but i have no problem with sonar-scanner as it finishes in 3 minutes.

Comment: Please note that SonarQube 6.0.1 does not exist... See all the available releases on http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/

Comment: lol... it is 6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried different things to solve this issue, including removing additional plugins, deleting the whole database and creating a new one. But the problem of too long time executing background tasks was consistent in addition to a new problem that the background task would not continue at all until I restarts the server. Due to this, the task that was not proceeding gets failed.

All these problem was solved when I upgraded my sonar-scanner version from 2.6 to 2.8.